# using caret for survival analysis (random survival forest)

Tags: r, r-caret

Is there a way to use `caret` for Survival Analysis. I really like how easy to use it is. I tried fitting a random survival forest using the `party` package, which is on caret's list.

This works:

```
library(survival)
library(caret)
library(party)


fitcforest <- cforest(Surv(futime, death) ~ sex+age, data=flchain,
                     controls = cforest_classical(ntree = 1000))
```

but using `caret` I get an error:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  repeats = 2,
)

cforestfit <- train(Surv(futime, death) ~ sex+age,data=flchain, method="cforest",trControl = fitControl)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: nrow(x) == length(y) is not TRUE
```

Is there a way to make these `Surv` object work with caret?
Can I use other survival analysis oriented packages with caret?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not yet. That is one of two major updates that should be coming soon (the other expands pre-processing).

Contact me offline if you are interested in helping the development and/or testing of those features.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: thanks Max, but what does contacting you offline mean, writing a post card? :)

Comment: I guess topepo expected you you to infer that he was the maintainer of the package. Just type in `maintainer("caret")` at the R console, It returns his email address.

Comment: @topepo: Is it still the case that `caret` has no survival analysis interface? (This is the most "relevant" hit in an SO search for "[r] survival" and it's not a particularly helpful accepted answer.)

Answer (score 3):

I have found no way to train survival models with caret. As an alternative, the mlr framework (1) has a set of survival learners (2). I have found mlr to be extremely user-friendly and useful.

1. mlr: http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/
2. survival learners in mlr: http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/integrated_learners/index.html#survival-analysis-15

Answer (score 2):

There is an increasing number of packages in R that model survival data, examples;

For lasso and elastic nets: BioSpear.

For random forest: randomForestSRC.

Best, Loic